# Show dialog as full screen or as dialog when using DialogFragment and Navigation Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, android-navigation

I have a DialogFragment which consists of a search EditText and a RecyclerView. When you click on a search item, dialog is dismissed and selected item is added to another list in the parent fragment.

I use navigation controller to navigate between fragments. This DialogFragment is currently defined with `fragment` tag in navigation graph XML. I use `findNavController().navigate(destinationId)` to open it and `findNavController().popBackStack()` to close it.

I want to show it as dialog in tablets and full screen on mobile devices but failed to do so.

I tried to create a custom dialog theme whose parent is `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DialogWhenLarge` and set it as `dialogTheme` in the app theme but it overrides attributes in the app theme, like status bar color. I also tried many solutions offered in questions asked here.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with Diologs set attribute in theme mad them fullscreen

```
<style name="NotificationDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">100%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">100%</item>
</style>
```